# Is it possible (and how) to connect a Belkin thunderbolt docking station to a Dell XPS 15 (with usb-c thunderbolt)?

Tags: usb, dell-xps, thunderbolt

I have the Belkin (thunderbolt) Docking station (http://www.belkin.com/us/F4U085/p/P-F4U085/) and I'd like to connect it to a Dell XPS 15" with a thunderbolt port in USB-C format.

Is it possible to connect it?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Thunderbolt 3 USB-C to Thunderbolt 2 converter.

Apple sells them for use with their new USB-C only MacBooks:
http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter

There are probably other manufacturers out there as well.

Should work without any problems. These converters are just pass-through and don't interfere with the workings of the Thunderbolt protocols.

Comment: I am curious, if the Type-C-with-Thunderbolt-protocol adapter (to the native ThB squarish connector) is just a pass-thru re-wiring, why the dongle is so bulky?