# Trying to connect a a Belkin dock thunderbolt 2 to a Dell XPS thunderbolt 3 with the Apple Adapter under Fedora 25

Tags: laptop, usb, fedora

As I read the title, it makes me feel like I'm trying to open a portal to an other galaxy ... well, maybe it's not that impossible ... at least on the paper it should work!

So here am I.

I have a [Belkin docking station](http://www.belkin.com/us/F4U085-Belkin/p/P-F4U085/) that I'd like to connect to my [Dell XPS 15](http://www.dell.com/fr/entreprise/p/xps-15-9560-laptop/pd?oc=bnx95603&model_id=xps-15-9560-laptop). This Dell has a USB-C type thundebolt 3 whereas the Belkin docking station uses a Thunderbolt 2 (mini-DisplayPort).

So, in order to connect them both, and following the recommendation [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1173235/is-it-possible-and-how-to-connect-a-belkin-thunderbolt-docking-station-to-a-de) and [here](https://twitter.com/BelkinCares/status/826222019058491392), I bought an [Apple Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter).

And today, I plugged them all together.

First thing first, they successfully plugged together, which is a small step, but a big one nonetheless.

But here come the issue ... Fedora doesn't detect all my hardware connected to it (a 4k screen, a keyboard, a mouse, the speaker and the ethernet cable. Yep, all that family.

I believe the best way to explain my situation, is to show you a little dmesg output, so here it comes :

```
[  488.534521] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[  488.534522] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[  488.534523] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[  488.534523] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.7-201.fc25.x86_64 xhci-hcd
[  488.534524] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:3e:00.0
[  488.534781] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[  488.534787] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[  488.534883] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[  488.535036] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[  488.535058] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[  488.535059] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[  488.535059] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[  488.535060] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.7-201.fc25.x86_64 xhci-hcd
[  488.535061] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:3e:00.0
[  488.535265] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[  488.535271] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[  488.896951] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  489.068266] usb 3-1: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
[  489.074304] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1657
[  489.074306] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  489.074308] usb 3-1: Product: Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter
[  489.074309] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[  489.074310] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: DTN6534002KH2YF4M
[ 1138.689803] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1138.760846] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: remove, state 4
[ 1138.760851] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[ 1138.761050] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Host not halted after 16000 microseconds.
[ 1138.762074] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
[ 1138.762223] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: remove, state 4
[ 1138.762228] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[ 1138.762494] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[ 1138.781929] pci_bus 0000:07: Allocating resources
[ 1138.781954] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 09-3d] add_size 1000
[ 1138.781963] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3e] add_size 1000
[ 1138.781964] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 3e] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 1138.781972] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1138.781973] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1138.781974] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 07-3e] add_size 2000
[ 1138.781976] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 2000 min_align 1000
[ 1138.781977] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x2fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 2000 min_align 1000
[ 1138.781979] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
[ 1138.781980] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
[ 1138.781981] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
[ 1138.781982] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
[ 1138.781984] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[ 1138.781985] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x002fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[ 1138.781986] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1138.781987] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x1fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1138.781988] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1138.781989] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x1fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1138.781992] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[ 1138.781993] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[ 1138.781993] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[ 1138.781994] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[ 1138.781995] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[ 1138.781996] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[ 1138.781998] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[ 1138.781999] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[ 1138.782000] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[ 1138.782000] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[ 1138.782001] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[ 1138.782002] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[ 1143.882451] pcieport 0000:07:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 1143.883388] pci_bus 0000:08: busn_res: [bus 08] is released
[ 1143.883437] pci_bus 0000:09: busn_res: [bus 09-3d] is released
[ 1143.883491] pci_bus 0000:3e: busn_res: [bus 3e] is released
[ 1143.883543] pci_bus 0000:07: busn_res: [bus 07-3e] is released
```

I'd like to note that I was able to test that Belkin (with the same hardware connected to it) using a Macbook Pro 2015 (with thunderbolt 2) and it worked correctly for all the items connected to the docking station.

So the error comes either from :

1. The Apple Adapter
2. The hardware from the Dell (something to enable/disable in the bios?)
3. From Fedora (I honestly doubt about it but well, who knows? (not me))

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207266),

> The Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter doesn't support
>   connections to these devices:
>
> Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) bus-powered devices
>
> USB-C devices, displays, and adapters that don't have Thunderbolt
>
> MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015) and later

Comment: Oddly enough, after altering my bios, I was able to make the dock almost work. The screen connected to the docking station works, but all the rest don't (keyboard, mouse, sound and network). So I'm not sure if your answer applies or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, good news, it works!

I don't know how really but after playing with the Bios the docking station works correctly.

USB Powershare must be enabled (I've tried without, and it didn't worked)

And regarding the other parameters, I've unchecked "Always allow Dell docks" and checked everything else.

The security level is at `User Authorization`.

[image]